# laravel DB multiple where but return one by one

Tags: laravel

I have an array with multiple values: `$x = w, x, y....` etc
I want to count the rows in a `DB` table but for each individual value of the array

DB Query:

```
$e = DB::table('fire_t')
          ->where('disk', $x[0])
          ->count();
```

I can do this for `1-5` values but what if there are more than `10` values
Is there any way to do it? need help

Answer (score 1):

In this case, you need to use [`groupBy`](https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/queries#grouping) besides that because you want to run your query depending on `array` of possibilities so you would use [`whereIn`](https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/queries#additional-where-clauses) instead this will
test over the entire given `array`

```
$disks = [1, 2, 3, 4];
$e = DB::table('fire_t')
          ->select(DB::raw('count(*) as  disk_count'))
          ->whereIn('disk', $disks)
          ->groupBy('disk')
          ->pluck('disk_count');
```

Comment: what's  ->withCount?? and using group by doesnot solve the problem cause it will eventually count all the variables inputed from array. I want seperate row count for invidual value of array

Comment: check the answer again this is an old version the naswer

Comment: Thanks I know this code but this code gives string(after converting stdclass to array). I need int. But thnks for the help

Comment: @devquery could you give an example of this problem

Comment: After executing this query it gives: object(Illuminate\Support\Collection)#1311 (1) { ["items":protected]=> array(3) { [0]=> object(stdClass)#1312 (1) { ["disk_count"]=> int(58) } [1]=> object(stdClass)#1303 (1) { ["disk_count"]=> int(25) } ...... I want only int 58, 25

Comment: all you need is to use `pluck` instead of `get` check the answer again